# Multiline python regex

Tags: python, regex, multiline, regex-greedy

I have a file structured like this :

```
A: some text
B: more text
even more text
on several lines
A: and we start again
B: more text
more
multiline text
```

I'm trying to find the regex that will split my file like this :

```
>>>re.findall(regex,f.read())
[('some text','more text','even more text\non several lines'),
 ('and we start again','more text', 'more\nmultiline text')]
```

So far, I've ended up with the following :

```
>>>re.findall('A:(.*?)\nB:(.*?)\n(.*?)',f.read(),re.DOTALL)
[(' some text', ' more text', ''), (' and we start again', ' more text', '')]
```

The multiline text is not catched. I guess is because the lazy qualifier is really lazy and catch nothing, but I take it out, the regex gets really greedy :

```
>>>re.findall('A:(.*?)\nB:(.*?)\n(.*)',f.read(),re.DOTALL)
[(' some text',
' more text',
'even more text\non several lines\nA: and we start again\nB: more text\nmore\nmultiline text')]
```

Does any one has an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an example of a really good question - complete specs, reproducible code, an accurate analysis of the problem - great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could tell the regex to stop matching at the next line that starts with `A:` (or at the end of the string):

```
re.findall(r'A:(.*?)\nB:(.*?)\n(.*?)(?=^A:|\Z)', f.read(), re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: @user1731620 Don't forget to 'accept' the answer that helps you out.

Comment: @jmague Don't forget to 'accept' the answer that helps you out.